# c# entity framework changing the contents of my lists

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, list, dynamic-proxy

I'm getting a really strange glitch and I believe entity framework is to blame. Here's the basic scenario thats going on. I have an entity object, Foo, with a navigation property collection, Bar. Foo in this context is being tracked by entity frameworks change tracking.
I run the following code, but the result is very strange

```
var NewBars = CreateBars(); //CreateBars returns a List<Bars> with two items

//After this code is ran, Foo.Bars AND NewBars will both be lists with 4 items.
//I think its because Foo.Bars has dynamic proxies, entity framework edits bars
//To re-insert the overwritten proxies. 
Foo.Bars = NewBars;
```

If I put a breakpoint at the var NewBars = CreateBars() line, and step through it piece by piece, everything will come out as expected. Foo.Bars will be a two item list, NewBars will be a two item list. But If I run execution with no breakpoints, or if I break point after I set Foo.Bars = NewBars, then both of these lists miraculously change to 4 item lists. Its weird to me that even the right hand value list is being changed.

At one point, even when I had the execution stopped at a breakpoint, I checked the contents of newbars and it was 2 the first time I looked, and then 4 the next time I looked. It changed while the program was at a halt, so I know theres something going on behind the scenes.

The problem is that because it keeps reinserting the proxies, Im getting primary key conflicts. If the proxies don't re-insert, then everything is fine. Im just wondering, how do I remedy this problem? I just simply want to set Foo.Bars to a new list of items. Any direction on this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to happen to the `Bar`s that are in `Foo.Bars` before you assign `newBars`?

You need to deal with them in some way. They are represeted by rows in a `Bar` table in your database, right?

You could remove these old `Bar`s entirely with something like:

```
dbContext.Bars.RemoveRange(Foo.Bars);
dbContext.SaveChages();
```

then assign your new bars:

```
Foo.Bars = NewBars;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Alternatively if you still want the old `Bar`s to exist in the db but just not be linked to `Foo` then you can do:

```
Foo.Bars=null;
Foo.Bars = newBars;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

(Of course this assumes your db schema allows this without violating any constraints)

Comment: Well, I guess what I was thinking was because in some cases, CreateBars would probably generate what was already in the list, and other times maybe it would generate a different list. But Basically in either case, I just basically wanted to write over whatever values were already in the database. And then if there were new values, to just add them in. But I guess I could always just clear out the lists before I generate new sets

Comment: You could also amend `CreateBars()` to pull the existing entries rather than creating new ones with the same id. If you do somethign like `newBar = dbContext.Bars.Find(id)` rather than 'newBar = new Bar{ ... ....}` you shouldnt have the same problem adding the results in the returned list